# Two subdomains (constraints) to same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several subdomains in my Rails app. Two of them are 'www' and 'market'.

I want both root of those subdomains (www.myapp.com and market.myapp.com) to go to the same controller, so I am trying to do:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'www' do
    root 'welcome#index'
end

constraints :subdomain => 'market' do
    root 'welcome#index'
end
```

But I am getting: 'Invalid route name, already in use: 'root''

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `:as` option. For example:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'www' do
  root 'welcome#index', as: 'root_www'
end
```